# python: read json and loop dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I'm learning python and i loop like this the json converted to dictionary: it works but is this the correct method? Thank you :)

```
import json

output_file = open('output.json').read()
output_json = json.loads(output_file)

for i in output_json:
        print i
        for k in output_json[i]:
                print k, output_json[i][k]

print output_json['webm']['audio']
print output_json['h264']['video']
print output_json['ogg']
```

here the JSON:

```
{   
 "webm":{
    "video": "libvp8",
    "audio": "libvorbis"   
 },   
  "h264":   {
    "video": "libx264",
    "audio": "libfaac"   
 },   
  "ogg":   {
    "video": "libtheora",
    "audio": "libvorbis"   
 }
}
```

here output:

```
> h264 
audio libfaac video libx264 
ogg
> audio libvorbis video libtheora webm
> audio libvorbis video libvp8 libvorbis
> libx264 {u'audio': u'libvorbis',
> u'video': u'libtheora'}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That seems generally fine.

There's no need to first read the file, then use loads. You can just use load directly.

```
output_json = json.load(open('/tmp/output.json'))
```

Using i and k isn't correct for this. They should generally be used only for an integer loop counter. In this case they're keys, so something more appropriate would be better. Perhaps rename `i` as `container` and `k` as `stream`? Something that communicate more information will be easier to read and maintain.

You can use `output_json.iteritems()` to iterate over both the key and the value at the same time.

```
for majorkey, subdict in output_json.iteritems():
    print majorkey
    for subkey, value in subdict.iteritems():
            print subkey, value
```

Note that, when using Python 3, you will need to use items() instead of iteritems(), as it has been renamed.

Comment: I'm getting ````AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'````

Comment: That suggests your JSON file doesn't contain a dictionary but instead a list. Perhaps it's a list of 1 dictionary? Try printing it out and seeing exactly what it contains.

Comment: @OivaEskola the iteritems() method has been renamed to items() in Python 3, so that might be the issue.

Comment: @LaurentVanWinckel it works for me, even in Django template, thanks :D

Comment: @OivaEskola use `.items()`.

Answer (score -4):

json_data = json.loads(url)

If list is there, then iterate:

```
 for majorkey, subdict in json_data.iteritems():
   for one_majorkey in subdict:
    for subkey, value in one_majorkey.iteritems():
        for each_subkey, valu_U in value.iteritems():
            for each_sub_subkey, value_Q in valu_U.iteritems():
                for each_sub_sub_subkey, value_num in value_Q.iteritems():
                    print each_sub_sub_subkey, value_num
```