# Dictionary Parsing in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having trouble parsing and obtaining data in from a dictionary data structure in Python.
Here's my dictionary:

```
x={"information":{"xyz":123},"received":true}
```

My question is that how do I access xyz? i.e I want to store the key xyz (not its corresponding value) in a variable named a. xyz is not a fixed value, it can be any string returned by the client.
Can anyone tell me how to obtain the value of this string?

Comment: There is no JSON in this post--anywhere

Comment: xyz is not known in advance. it can be any value. how do I read it then? @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @NoN01 you can do a `for (key, value in dict)` loop, that gives you all the keys.

Comment: You should loop over your items. 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147292/python-read-json-and-loop-dictionary

Comment: You should loop over your items. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147292/python-read-json-and-loop-dictionary

Comment: I'm trying this now: `for key in x
                          print key`
But this gives me a syntax error. Am I doing it right?

Comment: In your example, `x['information'].keys()[0]` gives `xyz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get keys of dict by using `keys()`. The value of `x["information"]` is a dictionary. So you can get keys this way:

```
x={"information":{"xyz":123},"received":True}
print x["information"].keys()
```

Output:

```
['xyz']
```